# How to count multi-child-node of an XML file via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently, I met a problem when using XSLT to do a check in some XML file just like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School> 
    <Grade name="grade1">
        <Class name=”Class1”>
            <LevelA>12</LevelA>
            <LevelC>1</LevelC >
        </Class>
    </Grade>
    <Grade name="grade2">
        <Class name=”ClassA2”>
            <LevelA>14</LevelA>
            <LevelC>0</LevelC>
        </Class>
        <Class name=”ClassB2”>
            <LevelA>10</LevelA>                 
            <LevelC>0</LevelC>
        </Class>
    </Grade>
    <Grade name="grade3"/>
    <Grade name="grade4">
        <Class name=”ClassA4”>
            <LevelA>12</LevelA>                 
            <LevelC>0</LevelC>
        </Class>
        <Class name=”ClassB4”>
            <LevelA>12</LevelA>                 
            <LevelC>2</LevelC>
        </Class>
    </Grade>
    <Grade name="grade5"/>
</School>
```

If All the Grade node contains Class (one or more), then write "Good" in the result XML file.

```
<xsl:if test="???">
    <p>
        <h3 style="color:green;">Good</h3>
    </p>
</xsl:if>
```

How to describe the condition at "???"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking if all the **Grade** elements contain a **Class**, check that there exist no **Grade** element without a **Class**.

Try this expression:

```
 <xsl:if test="not(//Grade[not(Class)])">
```